# snmp4j agent tool for generating java code for my MIB file

Tags: snmp4j

I am developing an SNMP agent using SNMP4J. I have a MIB file which I wanted to include in agent. Is there is any tool (open source) available for generating Java source code for my MIB file. or is there any link available which can guide me to develop the Java code for my MIB.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting http://www.mibble.org/ ...

> Mibble is an open-source SNMP MIB parser (or SMI parser) written in
>   Java. It can be used to read SNMP MIB files as well as simple ASN.1
>   files. Mibble is distributed as a Java library to make it possible to
>   include it in your applications.

or google for `MIB parsers` to get alternatives.